# Nest.js async onModuleInit invalid ordering

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I have `ServiceA` that depends on `RedisService`.

For `ServiceA` to be initialized, it requires for `RedisService` to already have been initialized (i.e. `RedisService.onModuleInit` to have been called & awaited)

This is ServiceA definition:

```js
// module config
@Module({
    imports: [RedisModule],
    controllers: [ServiceAController],
    providers: [ServiceAService, RedisService],
})
export class ServiceAModule {}

class ServiceA {
    constructor(
        private readonly redisService: RedisService,
    ) {}

    async onModuleInit(): Promise<void> {
        this.logger.debug('Initializing ServiceA...')
        const client = await this.redisService.getClient()
        // do some stuff with client...
        this.logger.debug('Initialized ServiceA')
    }
}
```

This is RedisService:

```js
class RedisService {
    constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {}

    async onModuleInit(): Promise<void> {
        ...
        this.logger.log(`Initializing Redis client at ${host}:${port}`)
        this.redis = new Cluster([{ port: port, host: host }], clusterConfig)
    }
}
```

As you can see, RedisService is also being initialized inside of it's onModuleInit lifecycle method.

What I see in logs:

```
[Nest] 41  - 01/08/2023, 10:30:19 AM   DEBUG [ServiceA] Initializing ServiceA...
[Nest] 41  - 01/08/2023, 10:30:19 AM     LOG [RedisService] Initializing Redis client at redis1:7000
// and here I get an error thrown from ServiceA.onModuleInit saying that Redis hasn't been initialized
```

And Nest.js even says "ServiceAModule dependencies initialized" before, but onModuleInit for Redis (which is a dependency) wasn't called yet. Why?

How to ensure onModuleInit execution order?

Comment: The order of initializing is based on the given provider list. however, the whole initialization process for a module is asynchronous, which means if a module has some asynchronous process while initializing(e.g. API call or fetching something) it skips that module until the process is finished. at this moment nest initializes other providers. so what is inside `RedisModule`?

Answer (score 0):

According to the nest docs:

> **onModuleInit():** Called once the host module's dependencies have been resolved.

It does not mean dependencies already are initialised.

At this point you cant be sure `onModuleInit` of Redis service runs before `onModuleInit` in ServiceA.

On the other hand, it is better to have `new Cluster` initialisation in your Redis controller to avoid situation when your service has no defined properties